# update command not working in gridview

Tags: asp.net

my code for update command:

```
public void update(name,email,phone)
{
    using {sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("some connection source"))
    {
        con.open();
        string str = "UPDATE register SET name = @name,email = @email WHERE phone = "@phone";

        using(sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand(str,con))
        {
            cmd.commandtype=commandtype.text;
            cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@name",name);
            cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@email",email);
            cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@phone",phone);
            cmd.executenonquery();
        }
    }
}
```

and my row updating event is this:

```
string name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
string email = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
int phone = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text);

update(name, email, phone);
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
bindgridview();
```

In my table phone is the primary key, when I press update button its not firing no change nothing. Can anyone see my code and tell me where I did wrong

Comment: there is no closing quotations(") in your update statement and where are you closing the conn

Comment: It looks like you have some typos in your code: 1) `using {sqlconnection con=...` : replace `{` with `(`. 2) `... WHERE phone = "@phone"` should be `...WHERE phone = @phone"` (unneeded quotation mark).

Comment: What event are you subscribing to on the Grid? Try to subscribe to the 'Updated' event instead of 'Updating'

Comment: Your code sample would throw a compiler error - please check the issues already mentioned an try to step-by-step debug your event handler and update method and tell us what you get.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive:rowupdated event not working ,

Answer (score 0):

Simple `Quotation`(") is missing in your update statement,unnecessary `{` after **using** and make sure your conn is also closed

Comment: I think there's no missing quotation mark - rather a superfluous one.

Comment: @Filburt: its 2phone only, no error, nothing.but its not updating.

Comment: @user1157685-If everything is fine then check with your connection string in web.config.